# How to make ipad like dropdownlist in desktop browsers using select tag of HTML and css only, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, mobile-safari

I am working on a project where i have to give some style to a select box(dropdown list) ....this page will work almost on every devices (responsive web design) i have to give style to a select box like this [image]

**In ipad its working but for desktop version ,how i can achieve same style for a select box using css only ? i m using HTML select tag `<select> ......</select>` for this.**

I want to use this markup

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You said `"in iPad its working"`. Are you talking about the addition of styles, or that the default iOS `select` box works? Can you provide a link to an example of where it's not working?

Comment: Hi,vonkly
 thanks for reply i m talking about default iOS select box ...mean in ipad there is no problem for getting above style because its default style but i want this same style for a select box for a desktop browsers  and i am using <select></select> tag for this i want to give above style using css only

Comment: Jamna, there is no way to change the "interior" of a select element with purely CSS. The iOS select element looks the way it does because for iOS, that *is* the default. Rc-ham's links are both viable ways to accomplish what you want to do on a desktop, with the first one coming closest to the graphical style that you want.

Comment: I think, we will not be able to give styling for a particular column but we can give style for all columns

Answer (score 0):

I did have some sort of recollection of maybe seeing menu like that before but at least i couldnt find it.

These however could quite easily be changed to what you want:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/ - Especially this one.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to change the default styling of a select box just with CSS alone for most Grade A browsers on the desktop, but I could be wrong.  You're going to have to use JavaScript and CSS to get what you are wanting.  I'm sure there are some jQuery plugins that could help you out.  Here are a few that I found, I've never tested these out but hopefully they provide some guidance.

[http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414161106/http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) (archived)

[http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120423005127/http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/) (archived)